# Multiple dropdown with jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am following this tutorial - http://www.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/

If you have a look at the demo - http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/ the second select appears once the first choice is made. While the third box appears when the second choice is made.

This is the ajax code:

```
  function showState(sel) {
    var primary_cat = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    $("#output1").html("");
    $("#output2").html("");
    if (primary_cat.length > 0) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch_state.php",
            data: "primary_cat=" + primary_cat,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#output1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $("#output1").html(html);
            }
        });
```

How can I made the second dropdown menu always appear, rather than appear and dissapear upon choice? I would still the same like it to populate whenever the first choice is made.

I tried eliminating lines

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $('#output1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
},
```

and

```
success: function(html) {
     $("#output1").html(html);
}
```

Individually and together but then it does not work.

Excuse my boring question but I'm still learning PHP and AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show both `select` tags, you will need to create a default value on the first select, since there have to be options for the second one based on the first one.

So what I would do is:

1. Remove the `<option value="">Please Select</option>` in the landing page from the `<select name="country" ...>`
2. Add the following code to the `<script>` where the `showState` function is defined (but before and outside the function):

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('select[name=country]').trigger('onchange');
   });
   ```

Like this you have a default value on the first select and the second one will always show with the options matching the selection in the first select.